# Derivatives for step function

Tags: limits, derivatives, dirac-delta

This question might be related a little bit to physics, but wanted to hear the answer from mathematics perspective and mathematician's intuition.

Imagine we have an object that moves in the time interval of $[t_0, t_1]$ and has the following trajectory : $x(t) + \epsilon\theta(t)$ where $\epsilon$ is infinetisemal number and $\theta(t)$ is given such as:

$
\theta(t)=
\begin{cases}
 1&t_0 < t < t_1\\
      0&\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$

Now, let's say I want to figure out the velocity. So we derivate and get:
$\dot x(t) + \epsilon \dot \theta(t) = \dot x(t) + \epsilon \delta(t-t_0)$.

I am trying to understand one thing now. So at $t_0$, object was at $x(t_0)$ and what was its speed at $t_0$ ? I get: $\dot x(t_0) + \epsilon \infty$, because at $t_0$, my delta function is infinity, so what is the speed at $t_0$ really ? Is it infinite ? but since $\epsilon$ is infinetisemal, multiplying it with infinity doesn't give me the intuitive answer what the speed is at that moment.

Comment: From the Mathematical perspective your statements doesn't make much sense, since in the real numbers there's no such thing as "an infinitesimal number", one would need to consider $\epsilon$ a small real number and then take the limit when it tends to $0$, the function $x(t)$ is not differentiable, $\delta$ is not a function, but a distribution, and as such  can't even be evaluated at $t_0$, let alone talking about its value being $\infty$, which is also not a real number.

Comment: You say $\delta$ is not a function, but we know that dirac delta is such a function that only at one point, it's infinity, in this case, it ends up to have a peak at $t_0$., so I can say that at $t_0$, it's it's infinite. Maybe forget about "real number" ?

Comment: The Dirac $\delta$ is not a function. It's a distribution (a generalized function), and distributions can't be evaluated at a single point, they need to be considered as part of an integral. That's the Mathematical way to formalize the concept of such "function".

Comment: I think what confuses me is then the piecewise definition people write for $\delta$ and that's why I could evaluate it. Is the reason why we can't evaluate that it's infinity at peak and it's meaningless where as in integral, it's 1 ?

Comment: Many physicist and mathematicians went to a lot to formalize the idea of an instantaneous spike. They come up with the theory of distributions. See for example [the Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), where it says, after the piecewise definition: "This is merely a heuristic characterization. The Dirac delta is not a function in the traditional sense as no function defined on the real numbers has these properties."

Comment: I totally get what you're saying.. All i meant was it doesn't neglect the fact that $\delta(x)$ is infinity at x=0 and 0 everywhere else. I might understand why it's not the real function as others since it's integral is 1, while traditional functions wouldn't have such answer, but my point is, $\delta (x)$ is still infinity at x=0. That was my whole point of my question, but seems like I mightn't be understanding lots of other things yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, note that you forgot the second boundary of the "bump", hence formally $\dot{\theta}(t) = \delta(t-t_0) - \delta(t-t_1)$.

Now, the question is a bit awkward, because we can consider such a quantity $x(t)$ mathematically of course, but it cannot really represent a position anymore, at least because of its distributional nature, which is unphysical.

You may fix this situation by arguing that the infinity behind the Dirac delta is compensated by the infinitesimality  of $\epsilon$, in other words, by setting something like $\epsilon \cdot \infty = 1$, but it is quite unnatural.

Physics, as well as science in general, is about choosing the right mathematical model in order to describe physical phenomena, which are seldom discontinuous (a professor of mine used to say jokingly that Nature was twice continuously differentiable). Sure, we can construct models with approximations, but they should be justified and not bring unnecessary mathematical illnesses on top of that.

In the present case, a more reasonable model would replace the discontinuities of $\theta$ at $t_0$ and $t_1$ by some sharp sigmoids and the delta function would be replaced by some narrow gaussian for instance.